# Building android app failing

Tags: android, node.js, nativescript

I'm trying to run an android app, using the command tns run android.

The build crash with the following error :

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'nativescript_barcodescanner'.

  > Failed to install the following SDK components:
  >     build-tools;27.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3
  >   Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.

The Sdk 27.0.3 is installed as shown in the attached file, so I do not know what I should do exactly

Please help[image: SDK installation]

Comment: Have you set `ANDROID_HOME` user environment variable to android sdk dir path?

Comment: You are missing the Android SDK platform-tools, that are unser the SDK Tools tab